# Split screen two sides in in iphone using UItableview in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, uisplitviewcontroller

I need to split iPad screen to two separate sides (Actual requirement is there is list of items in left side and we search through this items and selected items move to right side in one screen.) in iPad using objective c. I'm using XCode 4.2 and IOS 5. I know list these items in UITableview...

Please help me on this issue... Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a long way to go, but the place to start for an iPad application with 'two sides' would be to use the XCode template for a "Master-Detail" app.  Read the comments in the code, and understand how the two viewControllers interact with the UISplitViewController.  Read the View Controller programming guide and pay particular attention to the terms 'Container View Controller', 'Table View Controller' and 'Split View Controller': http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/